# FTPClient (Apache Commons)

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, socket-timeout-exception, passive-mode

I am getting a SocketTimeoutException while uploading a file. Retrieve file works fine for 2 files but then it fails on uploading different 2 files. The exception occurs during first file upload. This only happens in the Cloud. The code works fine on my local machine.

[image]

In stack trace it looks like keep-alive reply timeout(3 sec) throw this. How to setup FTP Timeout to fix this? Will increasing keep-alive reply timeout be sufficient? Or decrease keep-alive timeout?

Documentation:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html
[image]

Simplified code

```
ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(newPrintCommandListener(newPrintWriter(System.out),true));
ftp.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
ftp.setConnectTimeout(7200000);
ftp.setDefaultTimeout(7200000);
ftp.setControlKeepAliveReplyTimeout(3000);
ftp.setBufferSize(1024*1024);
ftp.setDefaultPort(21);

InetAddresslocalAddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
int localPort = 40044;
ftp.connect(host,port,localAddr,localPort);
int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)){
    ftp.disconnect();
    throw new IOException("Exception in connecting to FTPServer");
}

ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

boolean loginResult = ftp.login(user,pass);
if(!loginResult){
    throw new Exception("FTP login failed");
}

ftp.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
ftp.setKeepAlive(true);

try {
    FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(file1.toString());
    FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream(file2.toString());
    ftp.retrieveFile(remote1, fos1);//works fine
    ftp.retrieveFile(remote2, fos2);//works fine
    fos1.close();
    fos2.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
try {
    FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(file3);
    ftp.storeFile(remote3, fis1); //throws exception
    fis1.close();    

    FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(file4);
    ftp.storeFile(remote4, fis2); 
    fis2.close();        
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: Tried to increase the 3s timeout? If it just takes longer to get response for NOOP? Or just disable the whole thing with Zero (or less)? That feature shouldn't be necessary in most cases...

Comment: Thanks. Removing keep alive timeouts helped me.  I am calling the code from original answer 2x in a row and after first run I call logout and disconnect methods on FTPClient. After calling the code for the second time I receive **BindException: Address already in use** . After investigation it looks like problem is with releasing connection/ port from first run. Any idea how to correctly release connection/ port or wait for releasing before reconnect to FTP?

Comment: This is the way Apache has done their example: ``try{ftp.logout();} catch (final Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();} finally {if (ftp.isConnected()) {try {ftp.disconnect();} catch (final IOException f) {}}}``

Comment: Actually I think that Address already in use is because you define the local port. You don't need to do that - just use the simplified method: ´public void connect(String hostname, int port)´ and forget your "localAddr" and "localPort"

Comment: I changed the code to run all FTP downloads/ uploads in one "session". No logout/ disconnect and reconnecting again and it works now. I believe that problem is socket in TIME_WAIT state after disconnecting.

https://community.progress.com/s/article/Can-the-time-a-socket-spends-in-TIMED-WAIT-state-be-reduced
"An application employs a server socket that opens, accepts a connection, receives a message, returns a message, then closes the socket. This results in intermittent connection failure when this occurs many times and quickly. TIMED-WAIT state is a mechanism in TCP/IP stacks..."